# T-SQL how to find unused text item "Photo n"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I allow a user to label a photo they upload on our webpage with a unique PhotoName nvarchar(20).

I want to populate the webpage textbox field with a default value in case they don't want to bother coming up with a unique name. E.g. Photo 1, Photo 2 etc.

So I will need to check if 'Photo 1' has already been used and if so set the default to 'Photo 2'. If Photo 2 is used then default to Photo 3 etc.

They may also enter their own names such as "Mary's portrait".

Is there any T-SQL I can use to search for the first available 'gap' in the PhotoName column? E.g. It might return for example 'Photo 78' as free to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_parse()` in Sql Sever 2012+  to filter reminder of 'photo xxxx' string where xxxx represents an integer. Demo:

```
select coalesce(max(cast (nt as int)), 0) + 1 as new_number
from ( 
     values ('photo 20'),('ph 45'),('photo a'),('photo 5.45'),('photo 1E-3')
    ) t(title)
cross apply ( 
    select nt = case when title like 'photo %' then stuff(title,1,6,'') end 
    ) c1
where TRY_PARSE(nt as int) is not null
```

In older versions use `isnumeric(nt)=1 and not nt like '%[-+$.,\E]%'`